# Slowest Computational Complexity (Big-O)

Tags: algorithm, big-o, computation-theory

[image]

Out of these algorithms, I know Alg1 is the fastest, since it is n squared. Next would be Alg4 since it is n cubed, and then Alg2 is probably the slowest since it is 2^n (which is supposed to have a very poor performance).

However Alg3 and Alg5 are something I have yet to come across in my reading in terms of speed. How do these two algorithms rank up to the other 3 in terms of which is faster and slower? Thanks for any help.

Edit: Now that I think about it, is Alg3 referring to O(n log n)? If the ln inside of it means 'log', then that would make it the fastest.

Comment: O(n logn) is actually faster than O(n²), since O(logn) < O(n)

Comment: and `2^n = 2*2*...*2 < 1*2*3*...*n = n!` (at least for large n)

Comment: Big Oh doesn't tell you one algorithm is slower/faster than another in any sense of the word you're likely thinking of. It just tells you how *some quantity* (sometimes execution time or memory consumption on an idealized machine, sometimes the number of times some operation is performed, sometimes an entirely different quantity) changes asymptotically, i.e. as `n` grows.

Comment: “Out of these algorithms, I know Alg1 is the fastest, since it is n squared” Is this how your exam/homework question is phrased? the O() notation is about **asymptotic** complexity. There are n^2 algorithms with terrible constants in practice.

Comment: Well the question phrased it 'which is the more efficient or asymptotically fastest' but I was in a bit of a rush posting that question and just wanted a quick response so I can move onto the next bit of my studying lol

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The ascending order would be: [*n*·log(*n*) < *n*<sup>2</sup> < *n*<sup>3</sup> < 2<sup>*n*</sup> < *n*! for *n* ≥ 10](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+n*log%28n%29%2C+n%5E2+%2C+n%5E3%2C+2%5En%2C+n%21+for+n+from+0+to+12).

[image: Graph]

Also have a look at the [Big-O Algorithm Complexity Cheat Sheet](http://bigocheatsheet.com).